# Formatting Linq Outputs

Tags: c#, linq, string-formatting

I am trying to format the output so that that when the lines are printed it looks like this

```
Name          Price
LongName      Price
Name3         Price
```

I want it to look like a table. Here is my code

```
        var byValue =
            from i in invoices
            let total = (i.Quantity * i.Price)
            orderby total
            select i.PartDescription + " " + total;

        foreach (var element in byValue)
            Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.PadRight`:

```
select i.PartDescription.PadRight(maxLengthOfDescription) + total
```

If you don't know the max length, you can calculate it:

```
maxLengthOfDescription =
    invoices.Max(invoice => invoice.PartDescription.Length) + 1
```